# an animated show for kids where hero lifts a gauntlet that shows he is the destined hero

Tags: story-identification, animation

This kid imagines himself being in a tournament, but he was dreaming and his dad says he will train him if he cleans up for 2 years. When he is about to finish the time, his dad says 4 years and for him to sort the plushies so he does that, but he then has to deliver a letter and he gets hit by an acorn which a little flying purple monster threw at him. He makes it there and the letter slips into a crevice in a rock under a golden gauntlet. He lifts it and the people there gasp because only the destined can lift it, so he takes it and they train him.

Comment: That's a trip....